# safari ReferenceError: Can't find variable changestyledisplayblock

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, safari

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>The Goodies</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta name="generator" content="DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.74.0"/>
    <script type="text/javascript"> function changestyledisplayblock(id){ var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); for (var i=0; i &lt; ps.length; i++) { if (ps[i].id == id) { if ( ps[i].style.display == 'none' ) {ps[i].style.display = 'block';} else {ps[i].style.display = 'none';} } } } </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sect1" title="The Goodies">
        <div class="sect2" title="Multimedia">
            <div class="titlepage">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="title">
                            <a id="multimedia">Multimedia</a>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="bubble speech" id="bubble-speech-0 " style="display:none;">*0 : My first one !</p>
            <p class="bubble speech" id="bubble-speech-0 " style="display:none;">*0 : My second one !</p>
            <p>text <a class="marker" href="javascript:changestyledisplayblock('bubble-speech-0 ')">*0 </a>next</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here my html, i have the error ReferenceError: Can't find variable changestyledisplayblock, i'm not seeing any error, please help ! if i change my html extension to xhtml i dont see the problem any more ??? any explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That '<' should be a less than sign. Or was that an error in pasting the code?

Also, I'd advise against calling javascript code in anchor tags.